# Save Object in table related to another

Tags: symfony, doctrine

How can I create a new object when a cell is related to another table? In my case there exist a table with states, like id=1,state=active;id=2,state=inactive.

My Entity/States.php

```
class States
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
....
```

Entity/User.php

```
 ....
 /**
 * Set state
 *
 * @param \Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\States $state
 * @return User
 */
public function setState(\Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\States $state = null)
{
    $this->state = $state;

    return $this;
}
```

My AccountController:

```
....
$user = new User();
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$state = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FrontendAccountBundle:States')->find(1);

$user->setEmail($formData->getEmail());
$user->setStateId(1);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

This is not working and way to complicated: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata. It was so freaking easy in symfony1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `User` entity has a method `setState()`, which takes a single parameter of `$state`. That parameter must be of type `\Frontend\AccountBundle\Entity\States`.

In your controller, you obtain that object through this call:

```
$state = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FrontendAccountBundle:States')->find(1);
```

So when you go to set the State of the User, you don't need to bother with IDs. Rather, just set the State directly, and Doctrine will take care of the rest:

```
$user->setState($state);
```

Comment: As an alternative you could use: $state = $this->getDoctrine()>getPartialReference(''FrontendAccountBundle:States', 1);  This avoids loading the entire state entity when all you need is a reference.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html

Comment: Thanks, both to you. I guess I missed that in the docs or I was confused about the new notation. Anyhow I am used to the fine doctrine 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14131067/2400373

But in Symfony 4 change the line of `getRepository`:

```
$role = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository(Role::class)
                ->find(1);
$usuario->setRole($role);
```